# Number of quantifier alternations in prenex form of a formula

Tags: automata-theory, model-checking, program-verification, temporal-logic, first-order-logic

I'm currently studying [hyperlogics](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/fbs/publications/Hyperproperties.pdf) and in particular [HyperLTL/CTL*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4492).
In model checking algorithms for such logics the number of quantifier alternations appearing in a formula can play an important role regarding the complexity of the algo.

Working on better algorithms, a question came up which is actually more general:

*Let $\phi$ be a first order logic formula in negation normal form. Further let $\alpha(\psi)=k$ be the alternation depth of $\phi$, i.e. the maximal number of quantifier alternations in a branch of the formulas structure tree. What is the smallest number of quantifier alternation we can obtain for a prenex form $\psi^*$ of $\psi$? Is there an algorithm to constuct a prenex formula for which the lower bound holds?*

I did not fnd the question anywhere yet. I'm quit sure the answere should be that $\alpha(\psi^*)\leq\alpha(\psi)+1$ is always possible.

But I can't proof it. I can't find the right induction hypothesis.

Any ideas how to proof it, or where to find the answer?

Best, timtom

Comment: Yes, this is straightforward. Prove by induction on the complexity of the formula that it has a prenex form with $\alpha(\psi)$ alternations and the first quantifier block existential, and also a prenex form with $\alpha(\psi)$ alternations and the first quantifier block universal (I'm allowing blocks to be empty). Moreover, you can get $\alpha(\psi^*)=\alpha(\psi)$ if $\psi$ starts with a quantifier (but then you do not have choice for the first block type).

Comment: But isn't there a problem for the case $\psi=\exists\pi\psi_0$? Let $\alpha(\psi)=\alpha(\psi_0)=k$. By hypothesis there is a prenex form  $\psi_0^*$  with $\alpha(\psi_0^*)=k+1$ starting with a block of existential quantifiers and one starting with a block of universal quantifiers. But how can we deduce that there is one with alt.depth. k+1 and starting with a block of universal quantifiers for $\psi$? We only get it for a prenex form beginning with existential quantifiers..... where is my fault?

Comment: Hmm; maybe this is not the right induction hypothesis after all. The root of the problem is that $\alpha$ is a pretty terrible measure, as it does not obey any simple recursive definition. Consider instead the measures “the number of quantifier alternations starting from an existential state”, denoted $\alpha_\exists(\psi)$, and the universal analogue, $\alpha_\forall(\psi)$. These satisfy $\alpha_Q(\psi)=0$ for $\psi$ quantifier-free and $Q\in\{\exists,\forall\}$, $\alpha_Q(\psi_0\circ\psi_1)=\max\{\alpha_Q(\psi_0),\alpha_Q(\psi_1)\}$ for $\circ\in\{\land,\lor\}$, ...

Comment: ... $\alpha_Q(Qx_i\,\psi_0)=\alpha_Q(\psi_0)$, and $\alpha_{\overline Q}(Qx_i\,\psi_0)=1+\alpha_Q(\psi_0)$ where $\overline Q$ is the quantifier dual to $Q$. Then a straightforward induction shows that for $Q\in\{\exists,\forall\}$, $\psi$ has a prenex form $\psi_Q$ stating with a $Q$ block such that $\alpha_Q(\psi_Q)=\alpha_Q(\psi)$. Now, to relate this to $\alpha$, we have $\alpha(\psi)=\alpha_Q(\psi)$ if $\psi$ starts with quantfier $Q$, and in general, $\alpha(\psi)\le\min\{\alpha_\exists(\psi),\alpha_\forall(\psi)\}\le\max\{\alpha_\exists(\psi),\alpha_\forall(\psi)\}\le\alpha(\psi)+1$....

Comment: ... This implies what I wrote before: $\psi$ has a prenex form with $\alpha(\psi)$ alternations if $\psi$ starts with a quantifier, and for general $\psi$, it has both a prenex form starting with an existential block and a prenex form starting with a universal block with $\alpha(\psi)+1$ alternations.

Comment: You don’t need the formula to be in negation normal form, by the way. It works for arbitrary formulas; the clauses for $\neg$ are $\alpha_Q(\neg\psi_0)=\alpha_{\overline Q}(\psi_0)$.

Comment: Cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685690/number-of-quantifier-alternations-in-prenex-form-of-a-formula

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding the new measure correctly.  Example: let $\psi=\exists x_1\forall x_2\exists x_3\psi'$, where $\psi'$ is quantifier-free. I expected $\alpha_\forall(\psi)=1$ and $\alpha_\exists(\psi)=1$, but then  $\alpha(\psi)\leq\max\{\alpha_\exists(\psi),\alpha_\forall(\psi)\}$ would not hold, since $\alpha(\psi)=2$

Comment: No, $\alpha_\exists(\psi)=2$ and $\alpha_\forall(\psi)=3$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't get the definition of the measure. I missunderstood that you would mean by “the number of quantifier alternations starting from an existential state” the number of alternations from an existential to an universal quantifier - could you maybe rephrase it?

Comment: Another way to put it is that $\alpha_\exists(\psi)=\alpha(\exists x\,\psi)$, $\alpha_\forall(\psi)=\alpha(\forall x\,\psi)$. Or just follow the inductive definition, this leaves no room for interpretation.